# Akka Actor how to only process the latest message

Tags: scala, akka

Say I am sending messages to an Actor, when it is processing one message several more messages may arise. Now when it is ready to process the next message I want it to only process the latest message as the previous ones have become obsolete. How can I best achieve this?

Using the scala Actors library I was able to achieve this by first checking from my sender as follows:

```
if (myActor.getState != Runnable)
  myActor ! message
```

But I don't think I can do such a test in the Akka system

Comment: What message processing guarantees are your trying to ensure?

Comment: I believe Akka also has priority inbox. That might do what you want but this leads to the questions: what to do with the older messages? So you could have a custom inbox as suggested or have your actor store the timestamp of the last message processed (which will have to be stored in the message) and then drop all messages previous to that.

Answer (score 11):

There is no need to implement your own mailbox. At all.

Removed a lot of text and let this piece of code speak for itself:

```
// Either implement "equals" so that every job is unique (by default) or do another comparison in the match.
class Work 
case class DoWork(work: Work)

class WorkerActor extends Actor {
  // Left as an exercise for the reader, it clearly should do some work.
  def perform(work: Work): Unit = ()

  def lookingForWork: Receive = {
    case w: Work =>
      self forward DoWork(w)
      context become prepareToDoWork(w)
  }

  def prepareToDoWork(work: Work): Receive = {
    case DoWork(`work`) =>
      // No new work, so perform this one
      perform(work)
      // Now we're ready to look for new work
      context become lookingForWork
    case DoWork(_) =>
      // Discard work that we don't need to do anymore
    case w2: Work =>
      // Prepare to do this newer work instead
      context become prepareToDoWork(w2) 
  }

  //We start out as looking for work
  def receive = lookingForWork
}
```

This means that work will only be performed if there is no newer work in the mailbox.

Comment: It's a good idea, but there is a bug in your implementation: you should not relay on `work` equality: let's suppose we have 2 `work`s in our mailbox: `a from s1` and `a from s2` => `a from s2`, `DoWork(a) from s1` => `DoWork(a) from s1`, `DoWork(a) from s2`. So we'll process `a from s1` instead of `a from s2`. So you either should drop information about sender or fix your implementation. It could be important in case {`a from s1`, `b from s1`, `a from s2`}.

Comment: True, I made the assumption that the person implementing equals takes into consideration that a Work item is unique. That is besides the point in general tho. I'll add a disclaimer.

Comment: Am I mistaken, or don't you need to self forward DoWork(w2) before becoming a new prepareToDoWork? "Left as an exercise for the reader"... you didn't take maths at LTH by any chance?

Answer (score 5):

You could implement your own mailbox, this approach will not affect your actor implementation. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460213/406435) for solution with changes in actor implementation instead of custom mailbox implementation.

Implementation of mailbox that drops old messages on `enqueue`:

```
package akka.actor.test 

import akka.actor.{ ActorRef, ActorSystem }
import com.typesafe.config.Config
import akka.dispatch.{Envelope, MessageQueue}

class SingleMessageMailbox extends akka.dispatch.MailboxType {

  // This constructor signature must exist, it will be called by Akka
  def this(settings: ActorSystem.Settings, config: Config) = this()

  // The create method is called to create the MessageQueue
  final override def create(owner: Option[ActorRef], system: Option[ActorSystem]): MessageQueue =
    new MessageQueue {
      val message = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference[Envelope]

      final def cleanUp(owner: ActorRef, deadLetters: MessageQueue): Unit =
        Option(message.get) foreach {deadLetters.enqueue(owner, _)}

      def enqueue(receiver: ActorRef, handle: Envelope): Unit =
        for {e <- Option(message.getAndSet(handle))} 
          receiver.asInstanceOf[InternalActorRef].
            provider.deadLetters.
            tell(DeadLetter(e.message, e.sender, receiver), e.sender)

      def dequeue(): Envelope = message.getAndSet(null)

      def numberOfMessages: Int = Option(message.get).size

      def hasMessages: Boolean = message.get != null
    }
}
```

Note that I have to add this class into package `akka.actor` to send old message to dead letters using `InternalActorRef` like [implemented](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/dispatch/Mailbox.scala#L468) for `BoundedQueueBasedMessageQueue`.

If you want to just skip old messages you could implement `enqueue` like this:

```
def enqueue(receiver: ActorRef, handle: Envelope): Unit = message.set(handle)
```

Usage:

```
object Test extends App {
  import akka.actor._
  import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

  // you should use your config file instead of ConfigFactory.parseString
  val actorSystem: ActorSystem =
    ActorSystem("default", ConfigFactory.parseString(
"""
  akka.daemonic=on
  myMailbox.mailbox-type = "akka.actor.test.SingleMessageMailbox"
"""))

  class EchoActor extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case m => println(m); Thread.sleep(500)
    }
  }

  val actor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[EchoActor].withMailbox("myMailbox"))

  for {i <- 1 to 10} {
    actor ! i
    Thread.sleep(100)
  }

  Thread.sleep(1000)

}
```

Test:

```
$ sbt run
1
[INFO] <dead letters log>
[INFO] <dead letters log>
[INFO] <dead letters log>
5
[INFO] <dead letters log>
[INFO] <dead letters log>
[INFO] <dead letters log>
[INFO] <dead letters log>
10
```

See also [akka/Mailboxes](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/scala/mailboxes.html).