# Akka custom mailbox to concatenate updates

Tags: scala, akka

I'm not sure if I'm just trying to bastardize mailboxes with this solution but here's what I'm doing:

I have a financial application with an actor whose job it is to compute some analytics based on current market data and a portfolio of customer positions.

Each "Work" message to my actor includes a current snapshot of changed market data (since the last time) as well as changes to the portfolio (since the last time),

During peak times of stress - the actor can't process "Work" fast enough and so the mailbox starts buffering "Work" messages.

The issue: My work messages are **NOT** Lossy - So I can't just discard them and keep the latest, but at the same time it is very wasteful to process each "Work" message as they get quite stale especially as the actor falls further and further behind.

My solution: I am trying to implement a custom mailbox that can either enqueue a message if there are no current messages OR **Replace the current message with a NEW message that will have oldWork concatenated with NewWork**.  This way when the actor is ready to process more "Work" the item in the mailbox will be the latest accumulated information.

My Problem:

> Error:(98, 38) constructor Envelope in class Envelope cannot be accessed in class InstrumentedMailbox
>             val newEnvelope:Envelope = Envelope(mergedMessage,handle.sender)

It seems like Envelope doesn't like to be interfered with.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455681/akka-actor-how-to-only-process-the-latest-message/21457688#21457688) is ALMOST what I want - except I need to be able to modify the message and I can't seem to figure out how to create my own Envelope

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Apparently Envelope can be called with 2 or 3 arguments. `Envelope(message, senderActorRef)` or . `Envelope(message, senderActorRef, actorSystem)`.  The 2 argument apply method gives the error I described in my question.  The 3 argument constructor works.  Still interested in whether this approach has any merit or whether it would be better to do something else.  Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that processing one "big" (concat) message will take less time than processing the original smaller messages? This is true only if the time it takes to open a new message is comparable to the time it takes to process one message. Usually the "message opening time" is negligible. Maybe you should try to replace your working actor with a router instead.

Comment: Another point: if I look at the Akka documentation the only Envelope apply method i see is the 3-argument one: Envelope(message, senderActorRef, actorSystem).

Comment: I think you are indeed abusing the mailbox. As far as I understand it, the mailbox is just to have an async boundary. It is not meant to be customized with complex user code. I think you would be much better off with a "merger" actor that reads and combines messages immediately, and sends the combined messages to the actual worker on demand (work-pulling pattern)

Comment: @Quizzie: Concatenating the messages is a win in my particular instance because say I want to compute the current market value of a given position (reference MV = curMarketPrice * curQuantityOwned).  Let's also say my "work" request looks like Work(curPrice, curQuantity).  In this case - I'd just really care about the very latest message. In my case I'm doing this for a whole portfolio. So concatenating is really just taking the very latest individual Work messages.

Comment: @Quizzie: Also - the neat thing is that my concatenation has an upper bound because there are only X symbols and Y positions.  So if I don't concatenate I may be processing N * X and N * Y times (where N is how many messages I've fallen behind).

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn - I think I agree with your point.  I was trying to avoid having the second actor there, but technically speaking I think what you are proposing makes more sense.  I'm not sure what the etiquette is for submitting this as an answer.  Technically I believe I've gotten my solution to work - but your solution is probably the more correct way to do it.

Comment: I posted my response as an answer and added a link to the work pulling pattern

Comment: @eak0703: I believe you are contradicting yourself. On one hand you say that you can't discard old messages and keep just the latest. On the other hand you say that your concat solution "is really just taking the very latest individual Work messages" and that you only care about the lastest message.

Comment: @Quizzie: sorry for the confusion.  In my actual application my "Work" message is actually a List of many SubWork messages. I want one super set that contains the latest version of each SubWork message. Example: `Work((AAPL-$4), (MSFT-$5))`...next update `Work((AAPL-$5), (IBM-$2)`.  I want my concatenated version to contain: `Work((AAPL-$5),(MSFT-$5),(IBM-$2)`. The latest version of each price but making sure that i don't skip anything because otherwise I may lose data.  If I had completely discarded the first update I would not know about the price change for MSFT. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @eak0703: Ok, I understand. Then I think you chose the correct solution (the combining actor and work pulling).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are indeed abusing the mailbox. The mailbox serves just to have an async boundary. It is not meant to be customized with complex user code.

You would be much better off with an actor that reads and combines messages immediately, and sends the combined messages to the actual worker on request (see [work-pulling pattern](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/akka-work-pulling-pattern/))

Comment: I ended up scrapping my custom mailbox solution and implementing a "combining" actor and then changing my current actor to pulling work as quickly as it can.  This approach also made it easier for me to instrument my combining actor to output how far the "worker" has fallen behind and when it is "catching up".